# D3 - Unnecessary values in X Axis

Tags: d3.js

I'm creating a line chart using D3 and I would like to show in X Axis only values that exist in my data array.

```
var svg = d3.select("div#chart").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


// Add the X Axis
var xAxis = svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%d/%m %H:%M")))
.selectAll("text")
.attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.attr("y", 0)
.attr("x", 9)
.style("text-anchor", "start");
```

The full code is here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsjnzey2/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [tickValues](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/README.md#axis_tickValues):

> If a values array is specified, the specified values are used for ticks rather than using the scale’s automatic tick generator.

Thus, to create an array with the dates in your data array, you can simply write:

```
.tickValues(data.map(d=>d.date))
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jy2qL7ka/

And here the same code in a Stack snippet:

```js
var margin = {
            top: 20,
            right: 80,
            bottom: 90,
            left: 50
          };
          var data = [
           {date: '2017-01-15 21:39:12', value: 0},
            {date: '2017-01-15 21:43:12', value: 1},
            {date: '2017-01-15 21:44:12', value: 0},
            {date: '2017-01-15 21:48:12', value: 1},
            {date: '2017-01-15 21:50:12', value: 0},
            {date: '2017-01-15 21:53:12', value: 1},
            {date: '2017-01-15 21:55:12', value: 0}
          ];
          
          var width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

          var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
          var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
          var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

          // define the line
          var line = d3.line().curve(d3.curveStep)
            .x(function (d) {
              return x(d.date);
            })
            .y(function (d) {
              return y(d.value);
            });

          var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

          // format the data
          data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
          });

          x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
            return d.date;
          }));

          y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return d.value;
          })]);


          // Add the line path.
          svg.append("path")
            .data([data])
            .attr("class", "line")
            .style("fill", "none")
            .attr("d", line)
            .style('stroke', 'blue');

          svg.selectAll("dot")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("r", 4)
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.date); })
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.value); })
            .style("fill", 'blue');

          // Add the X Axis
          var xAxis = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
.tickValues(data.map(d=>d.date))
.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%d/%m %H:%M")))
            .selectAll("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .attr("y", 0)
            .attr("x", 9)
            .style("text-anchor", "start");
          
          // Add the Y Axis
          svg.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @gerardo-furtado for your reply!
Your suggestions working fine!

But if I update the dates to close dates, the labels are became on above other.
Look at my example again: [JSFiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/tsjnzey2/4/)

Comment: Well, that's **another** problem. Your specific problem here was solved. I suggest you post another question regarding this other problem.